# Architeture Web Server, Application Server and DB Server

Tags: database, web, architecture, webserver, application-server

For the best of my knowledge this architeture

- **Web Server -> Application Server -> DB Server**

is better than

- **Web Server -> DB Server**

But I do not know the reasons. Does anybody know?

[image]

My Application Server is an Optimization Server for steel process.

Thanks a lot.

Regards,

Alex

Answer (score 1):

All architectures are good as long as they meet the requirements and do the job. Moreover, **Web Server -> DB Server** is generally better because every new tier slows down the system. In general a call between tiers is 100 times slower than a call between logical layers within one process or between processes on the same machine. But there are cases when a separate tier is required such as Application Server from your diagram. For example, under high pressure **Web Server -> Application Server -> DB Server** might be better from scalability perspective when Web Server just gets requests and queues business logic to be processed asynchronously on the  Application Server. In this case one can add as many Application Servers as he wants. This architecture is quite popular in the CQRS and Event Sourcing world. But usually people just over-complicate things and pick a technology to use just because it's a brand new and fancy.

To sum it up: a new tier is an evil but sometime a necessary one.